# run tns build android --release .... The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: android, nativescript

I want to publish app to playstore.

I follow [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps)

1. Create .keystore file
2. Now I `run tns build android --release --key-store-path <C:\project\my-key.keystore> --key-store-password <mypass> --key-store-alias <myaliasname> --key-store-alias-password <mypass>`

Error

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Can you ask me any idea please, what is the problem ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using these symbols in your command `<` / `>`, do you? It should be just the value without those greater / less than symbol.

Comment: Example(Windows): tns build android --release --key-store-path C:\keystore\Telerik.keystore --key-store-password sample_password --key-store-alias Telerik --key-store-alias-password sample_password

Answer (score 3):

Try the below one :

```
tns build android --release --key-store-path C:\project\my-key.keystore --key-
store-password mypass --key-store-alias myaliasname --key-store-alias-password mypass
```

Comment: please improve the code readability. The answer is not helpful when its all muddled up like this.